# How to make this C structure in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, structure

I just finished basic C, and now moved onto JAVA.

I want to make something like linked list structure of this type:

```
typedef Node{
  int a;
  char b;
  Node *next;
} NODE;



NODE *new1 = (NODE *)calloc(1,sizeof(NODE));
```

However my research indicates that there is no such a things like this structure in JAVA, instead they suggest I use

1. HashMap
2. List

but unfortunately, I don't think I can manage my code if I use List.
and I don't know exactly how to use `HashMap` for with different types.

How can I use single key and and multiple data types in `HashMap`?

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers. The Java equivalent of a structure is a `class`.

Comment: Why don't you just define a class?

Comment: Use an object reference from one instance of Node to another

Comment: I'm not sure why you think HashMap is the same to a LinkedList.

Comment: Java is not an acronym, so it's not JAVA.

Comment: If you're accustomed to C, you'll also need to know that a Java variable whose type is a class actually stores a reference to the structure, not the structure itself.  These references behave very much like C pointers.  So the Java declaration `Node next;` works just like the C declaration `Node *next;` - if it's a field, then its value is `null` until you assign something to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no such a things like Structure in JAVA,

To that, I'd say false. You have `class` instead of `struct`

You can almost exactly copy what you have into Java.

```
class Node{
    int a;
    char b;
    Node next;
}
```

...

```
Node new1 = new Node();
```

However you choose to use this class will require you to learn more Java and Object Oriented programming in general.

Note: `LinkedList` is already a Java class. You don't need to define your own unless for learning

Comment: Thanks! it help a lot :3

Answer (score 0):

This is the java version of your code in C

```
public class Node {
    int a;
    char b;
    Node next;
}
```

..

```
Node head = new Node();
```